# How does #define know when to stop looking?

Tags: c++, preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I use a macro in C++ to switch between compiling logging or not:

```
#define MAYBE_LOG(msg) 
#ifdef PRINT_MSGS 
ALWAYS_LOG(msg) 
#endif
```

How does the `#define` know where the ending is? The `#endif` refers to the `#ifdef`, not the `#define`.

Comment: Assuming the intent is to define a three-line macro, there are two problems here: first you need a backslash at the end of each line but the last; and second, preprocessor directives are not allowed inside a macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in the question does two separate things: it defines a macro named `MAYBE_LOG` with no body and, if `PRINT_MSGS` is defined, it uses a macro named `ALWAYS_LOG`. If that's not what it's supposed to do, then, yes, it needs to be changed. Since the question doesn't say what the code is supposed to do, this is just a guess:

```
#ifdef PRINT_MSGS
#define MAYBE_LOG(msg) ALWAYS_LOG(msg)
#else
#define MAYBE_LOG(msg)
#endif
```

The reason for doing it this way (and not using `\` on each line to extend the macro definition is that you can't put `#if` conditions inside the definition of a macro.

Comment: That is possibly a solution. But it won't work if the OP plans on enabling and disabling logging by redefining PRINT_MSGS at various points in the source code.

Comment: @TonyK -- there are many things that won't work if currently unspecified requirements are added. As I said, since the question doesn't say what the code is supposed to do, all anyone can do is guess. Or remain silent.

Comment: Yes, of course. I was just clarifying things for the OP.

Answer (score 4):

`#define` ends at end of the line (which might be extended with final `\`)

Comment: So my code is wrong and I need to use "\" on each line except the last?

Comment: You cannot have `#ifdef` pre-processing in `#define`.